# How can I validate input only after it was changed?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

Probably this is pretty dummy question, but I couldn't find a simple solution (something like special HTML5 attribute).

For example I have a simple form with enabled validation for `email` field:

```
<form>
    <input required type="email" placeholder="email@gmail.com"></input>
</form>
```

And some styles for `:valid, :invalid` pseudoclasses:

```
input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

So, when I'm opening a page with this form, input is already red bordered, because it's empty. The question is - how can I enable validation only after user has changed smth?

Comment: I don't know why everyone missed this, but it's *placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [onchange event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp), see:

```
<!-- added a ID to get it easier later -->
<input required id="myInput" type="email" placehodler="email@gmail.com"></input>
```

In your css, use classes to set your styles:

```
input.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

In your javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').onchange = function(){
     // validation code here

     this.classList.add('valid') // if validation is true
     this.classList.add('invalid') // if validation is false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Input value will be checked dynamically with every key pressed by the user. You can adjust the requirements by yourself.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

function validate(){
  if (input.value.length > 2) {
    input.className = 'valid';
  } else {
    input.className = 'invalid';
  }
}
```

```css
.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input required type="email" placehodler="email@gmail.com" id='input' onkeyup='validate()'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a wide open set of methods to achieve this. I'll go for the easiest ones: `blur` || `input`.

You can attach the `input` or `blur` events and validate when they happen. The difference is that `blur` will be called when the user focuses another element (clicks the submit button, goes to another input, clicks elsewhere in the page, whatever) and `input` is called right after the user changes something in the input, usually by keypressing, but also happens when the user pastes or cuts. `input` is the "official" html5 way of listening to input elements.

```
document.getElementById('emailInput').oninput = function(){
    // validateinput
}
```

Also, you can go for `change` event, that is exactly the same as `blur` but it fires only if the user changed the content. The "bad" thing is the same as `blur`: no live validation while writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the querySelector to make the distinction between valid and invalid instead of css. You should use `keyup` or `keydown` instead of `change` event because change requires you to refocus to verify.

JS

```
myform.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (myform.querySelector('input:invalid')) myform.querySelector('input:invalid').style.border = "1px red solid";
  else myform.querySelector('input:valid').style.border = "1px solid green";
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
  <input required type="email" placeholder="email@gmail.com"></input>
</form>
```